# update some values in more than 1 column with a sum of values from the same columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example there is a table T

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
a    x    y    z    s0   s2
b    x    y    z    s1   s3
c    x    y    z    s4   s5
a    x1   y1   z1   s6   s7
b    x1   y1   z1   s8   s9
c    x1   y1   z1   s8   s9
```

after the update it should look like

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5  col6
a    x    y    z    s0    s2
b    x    y    z    s1    s3
c    x    y    z    s0+s1 s2+s3
a    x1   y1   z1   s6    s7
b    x1   y1   z1   s8    s9
c    x1   y1   z1   s8+s6 s9+s7
```

Answer (score 1):

You are a bit vague about the rules being used for the transformation.  The following may do what you want:

```
update t
   set col5 = (select sum(col5) from t2 where t2.col2 = t.col2 and t2.col1 in ('A', 'B')),
       col6 = (select sum(col6) from t2 where t2.col2 = t.col2 and t2.col1 in ('A', 'B'))
   where col1 = 'C';
```

Comment: thanks @Gordon Linoff but do you know is it possible to combine 2 selects into 1 since all conditions are the same

Comment: besides, looks like it'll work till col2 (or any other matching parameter) is not null